# How to use nextLine() after sending ControlD EOF

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, eof, nosuchelementexception

For my team's programming project, we have a board game, where the user has various inputs at different stages.

When the user wants to quit in the middle of the game, we want the user to press Control+D (which throws the NoSuchElementException) which I want to propagate back to the main menu to allow the user to begin a new game without re-running the program.

I run into problems when I try to access any Scanner .next* methods - it throws the same exception with "No line found".  As I read somewhere, the EOF makes hasNext* return false.

The EOF completely stops the Scanner, and any new Scanner from working, as I get the same problem.  So, the EOF works exactly as I want it to, until we ask for more input from the user.

(I have done this in C successfully)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean run = true;
        String str;
        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (run)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println(scan1.hasNextLine());
                str = scan1.nextLine();
                System.out.println(str);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error");
                //scan1.nextLine(); // this throws the "No line found"
                run = false;
            }
        }
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(scan2.next()); // without scan1, this throws the "NoSuchElementException"
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to continue Scanning after we EOF?

Comment: You might need a keyboard listener to implement what you have in mind, in which case a simple console program could not handle this.

Comment: Don't use Ctrl/d. Use another keystroke.

Comment: Bummer.  Thanks for that.